# To pageup and pagedown without reserved lines

Tags: scrolling, navigation

When I scroll a whole page up by `ctrl-f`, and down by `ctrl-b`, vim reserves 2 lines, and repeats them both in the previous GUI window and the present one. 
But I expect it not to repeat lines, because now that the "turning" of pages is not a really "turning" but with a small shift, this makes me harder to visualize the new position which it is.

That is to say, if line 1 to line 30 is shown in present window, and to simplify matters suppose none is wrapped, then when I press `ctrl-f`, the subsequent GUI window will display line 29 to 58. 
But I want it to show line 31 to 60, and so on. What should I set in `.vimrc`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It dawned on me that why do I not move page down and further scroll two lines, and same can be said on page up.

```
" Scroll a page with no repeated lines,
" while default shows two lines in both present and next window
nnoremap <C-f> <C-f><C-e><C-e>
nnoremap <C-b> <C-b><C-y><C-y>
```

I am finding myself on the right track of being a vim master.

Answer (score 4):

I like to use the following:

```
nnoremap <c-f> z+
nnoremap <c-b> z^
```

Comment: Wow, I know little about `z` before this. Always learning!